# setting exclusiveTouch to custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios5, uitableview

I am trying to set the exclusiveTouch property to my custom UITableViewCell.

However, adding this code does not seem to work.

```
for (UIView *view in cell.subviews)
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]])
         {
             view.exclusiveTouch = YES;
         }
}
```

Could someone help me figuring out what I am missing or what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure but give it a try:

```
cell.exclusiveTouch = YES
cell.contentView.exclusiveTouch = YES
```

Comment: I tried it out.. but it does not seem to work.. in my cell I have a UILabel, which covers the entire cell.. would that make a difference? would I need to add the exclusiveTouch to the Label? because that also does not seem to work..

Comment: It should not matter as long as the label has userInteracionEnabled propperty set to NO, wich is it's default.