# How to handle multi-touch in UITableViewCell with buttons?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I have custom table view cells that each have 3 buttons. Selecting a row in the table pushes another view controller; pressing one of the buttons shows a modal view.

If, with two fingers, I select a row, and press a button, both the controller gets pushed and the modal view appears . I've tried setting a flag in the buttons' `TouchDown` event and returning `nil` in
    `tableView: willSelectRowAtIndexPath:`
if the flag is true, but the flags gets set to false in the buttons' `TouchUpInside` event handler, so the `tableview: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` still gets called.

How can I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your button's touch down method, set the `UITableView`'s `allowsSelection` property to NO. Then in the touch up (both inside and outside) handler set it back to YES.

Comment: In the case when the button is touched first and then the cell, this works; when the cells is touched first and then the button, it sometimes worked, sometimes didn't so I set `allowSelection` back to YES with a perform selector with delay of 0.0

Answer (score 0):

It helps

```
cell.contentView.exclusiveTouch = YES;
cell.exclusiveTouch = YES;
```

[setting exclusiveTouch to custom UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616855/setting-exclusivetouch-to-custom-uitableviewcell)