# Multi touch on UITableView with custom cells

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have UITableView with custom cells, when i tap more than one finger on cells (2 finger on two cells), it check both. Can i disable multitouch on table? 
I tried
 `tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;` 
and 
`tableView.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;` 
and 
`cell.exclusiveTouch = YES`; 
But nothing work. 
Please help me to find out solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps me-

```
    cell.contentView.exclusiveTouch = YES;
    cell.exclusiveTouch = YES;
```

I see answer here - [setting exclusiveTouch to custom UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11616855/setting-exclusivetouch-to-custom-uitableviewcell)